# How to Fix Flickering Lamp (That Stops Flickering When I Unscrew and Rescrew)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bulb, lamp

I just bought a set of two lamps (https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/pdp/alcott-hill-amell-2539-table-lamp-set-w003190357.html). The lamps have   settings for off, low light, medium light, and high light which can be changed by just touching the base of the lamp.

I put 60 Hz LED bulbs in both lamps. One of the lamps starts to strobe more and more the brighter I turn up the light on it, as if the Hz drops as I turn up the brightness. I use the term strobing because the flashing occurs at a steady pace, not like erratic flickering.

The other lamp works fine with the same light bulb. I've tried multiple new bulbs and this happens every time. The weird thing is the LED bulb stays steady when I leave the lamp on, unscrew the bulb, and screw it back in. Now I have a morning routine of turning on the lamp, unscrewing and re-screwing the bulb and it works correctly all day until I turn it off and back on.

I don't want to have to do this every time I turn the light on, so I was hoping someone on here might have experienced the same thing and can point me in the right direction for how to fix it.

The lamps now seem to be sold out so I don't think I'll end up getting a replacement but I'm trying that avenue as well.

Comment: Sounds like by process of elimination you have determined that one lamp is faulty. **How can we help you with that?**, we do not know much about the lamp other then it is touch to control lamp.

Comment: @AlaskaMan There are repeatable steps to fix the issue in about 10 seconds. Inconvenient, but seems permanently fixable. Someone more knowledgeable on the subject than I am  may have experienced this and have a fix. I would rather not just throw it away if it can be fixed. I will add a link to the lamp.

Comment: OK.  the point was, we did not know what lamp you have. I see you have added a link. This will help to inform an answer. **Have you tried to find the manufacturers website for the manual?, not just the wayfair retail site.

Comment: The added link provides all of the specifications of the lamp on the right-hand side under "Product Overview" (Response to original prior comment)

Comment: Chinese maker so not much hope of  finding a website or of it being easy. The specs do not tell us much. But it is warranted. (*at least in print*) Contact Wayfair.

Comment: Yep, goose egg.

Comment: Perhaps you can replace the touch control sensor or bypass the circuitry for the touch control and put a switch on It. I am not sure we can help unless we can see the way it wired and what parts it uses